# Intro Js not working on IE8. is there a workaround?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, intro.js

http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/

This is the demo page
In IE I get

Webpage error details:

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
>   Timestamp: Tue, 18 Nov 2014 07:48:40 UTC

Message:

```
Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type
that does not accept the focus.
  Line: 932
  Char: 5
  Code: 0
  URI: http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/intro.js?v=060
```

any help?